# IIS rewrite rule not working on Azure

Tags: iis, azure, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have a URL rewrite rule to redirect from non-www to www. But a non-www address just gives a 404 error.

Anyone spot the problem? The site is hosted on Azure.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <compilation batch="false" />
        <customErrors mode="off"/>
      </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
          <add name="iisnode" path="keystone.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="FilanthropyStar">
              <match url="/*" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="keystone.js" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^filanthropystar.org$" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.filanthropystar.org/{R:0}"
                  redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the match URL be `(.*)` and the action URL `http://www.filanthropystar.org/{R:1}`?

Comment: Testing that rule in IIS, or production makes no makes no difference